How to get item from dictionary and add to list? Getting an item from a room
def display_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print('Welcome to Colossal Cave Adventure Remake')
    print('Move commands: South, North, East, West')
    print("Collect 9 items before encountering the Dragon or be eaten by the Dragon.")
    print("Move commands: South, North, East, West")
    print("To add item to inventory use: Get item")
display_instructions()

# The starting room
current_room = 'Cave Entrance'
inventory = []
item_count = 0
move = ''
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Exit', 'Get Item']
item_key = 'item'
villain = 'Dragon'

# Define room connections
rooms = {
  'Cave Entrance': {'item': 'No Item', 'South': 'Troll Region', 'North': 'Giants Room', 'East': 'Magnificent Caverns', 'West': 'Pearl Room' },
  'Giants Room': {'item': 'Golden Eggs', 'East': 'Hall of Mists', 'West': 'Forest Region', 'South': 'Cave Entrance'},
  'Hall of Mists': {'item': 'Diamonds', 'West': 'Giants Room'},
  'Forest Region': {'item': 'Magic Staff', 'South': 'Volcano Region', 'East': 'Giants Room'},
  'Volcano Region': {'item': 'Ring of Doom', 'North': 'Forest Region'},
  'Pearl Room': {'item': 'Magic Pearl', 'East': 'Cave Entrance', 'North': 'Pirates Room'},
  'Pirates Room': {'item': 'Pirates Chest', 'South': 'Pearl Room'},
  'Magnificent Caverns': {'South': 'Plover Room', 'West': 'Cave Entrance'},
  'Plover Room': {'item': 'Emeralds', 'North': 'Magnificent Caverns'},
  'Troll Region': {'item': 'Golden Chain', 'North': 'Cave Entrance', 'East': "Villain's Lair"},
  'Villains Lair': {'item': 'Dragon', 'West': 'Troll Region'} # Villains Lair
}

def user_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}.')
    print(f'Your inventory is {inventory}.')
    print(f"In this room you see {rooms[current_room]['item']}.")
    print('-------------------------------')


while move != 'Exit':
    user_status()
    move = str(input('Make a move, Get item or Exit to quit: \n')).title().strip()
    if move not in directions:
        print('Invalid Input. Try Again!')
        continue


    # To get item from room
    if move == 'Get Item':
        if 'item' in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            if 'item' not in inventory:
                inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
        else:
            print(f"There's no", rooms[current_room]['item'] + " here.")

            #Delete Item From Dictionary
            #del rooms[current_room]['item']
        #if encounter villain in room
        if villain in rooms[current_room].keys():
            # If Lose
            if len(inventory) < 9:
                print(f'You lost fight with {rooms[current_room][villain]}.')
                break
            #Win
            else:
                print(f'You won. You beat {rooms[current_room][villain]}!')
                break
    elif move == 'Exit':
        print("You've exited the game. Bye! Thanks for playing!")

    # If Move Is Right Direction
    elif move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
    else:
        # If Wrong Direction
        print("You have a wall in the way. Try again")

When I use the 'get item' the console tells me invalid move. I've tried multiple ways to get item from many different sites but I've had no luck. This was my final attempt.
I have 'get item' in directions, so it should be a valid move. I have inventory [] also.
I'm a beginner to Python.

Your code is invalid because of the part you block-quoted out. Not only that but when I try to fix it on my side, I then have unreachable code (that will never run) so I don't know how you intend this to actually run. If people have to guess at your implementation, they won't be able to accurately answer

if item in rooms[current_room]['item']: I think you meant if "item" in rooms[current_room]:

your code contains an if inside triple quotes that is commented. But then this leaves the next code wrongly indented and with an invalid else. You need to fix your code so it's executable. Then post what your input is and what is the output you receive, so we can reproduce the problem.

When I input "get item" the console tells me invalid move but I have "get item" in my directions. It doesn't throw any error message it basically does nothing.

"get item".capitalize() produces "Get item", which is not a key in the dictionary. Try .title() instead.

I changed .capitalize() to .title() and know the else statement runs.  It says "There's no item in room". So there's progress.

def user_status():  # indicate room and inventory contents
    print('\n-------------------------')
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}.')
    print(f'Your inventory is {inventory}.')
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print(f"In this room you see {rooms[current_room]['item']}.")
    else:
        print("This room is empty.")
    print('-------------------------------')


while move != 'Exit':
    user_status()
    move = input('Make a move, Get item or Exit to quit: \n').strip().title()
    if move not in directions:
        print('Invalid Input. Try Again!')
        continue

    if move == 'Get Item':
        if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
            del rooms[current_room]['item']
        else:
            print("There's no item here.")
    ....


What use is this if you don't even try to explain what you fixed?

Thank you very much. This worked perfectly. I didn't think about putting an 'if' statement in def.

@roganjosh I think it's pretty self-explanatory. OP seems to get it. But, feel free to downvote. Also, feel free to improve the answer. I've started making all my answers community wikis. Anyone with >100 rep can edit it.
